dlopen fails to load shared library in android NDK application
I am trying to load a shared library in my android application using ndk, however dlOpen is failing with following error:

----- Failed to open file -----
dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_adreno.so" needed or dlopened by "/data/app/~~VinTTwXtrVynTeLYP6ZLOA==/io.csrohit.ndkgl-eBpYXT0F8mUGRkEbXctU_Q==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libndkgl.so" is not accessible for the namespace "clns-4"

below is the code snippet used to load the library:
    void * handle = dlopen("/vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_adreno.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(gpFile, "----- Failed to open file -----\n");
        fprintf(gpFile, "%s\n", dlerror());
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(gpFile, "----- file opened properly -----\n");
    }

What am I doing wrong here?
I am expecting to successfully load the shared lib and then read thr function pointers from it.

are you sure you have permission to read that file in that location? Android became very strict lately.

I am not aware if any specific permissions are required for this. If anybody has any idea about this, it would be really helpful
